# BCP from one server to another without intermediate file?

Tags: sql, bcp

I have a BCP process to move data from one server to another server, but it takes two trips: one to a .dat file, and one to the destination server.  Is there any way to send all of the data directly to the destination server?

I'm trying to improve the speed of this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using SQL Server 2005+, then SSIS; BCP writes to a file, but SSIS can go from one connection to another.  Here's a few articles on how to bulk load data in SSIS:

Optimizing Bulk Import Performance
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421(v=sql.105).aspx

The Data Loading Performance Guide
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(SQL.100).aspx

We Loaded 1TB in 30 Minutes with SSIS, and So Can You
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533(v=sql.100).aspx